# Python iterating over array with different sizes

Tags: python, arrays, iteration, calculation

I am trying to perform a simple calculation and place the outputs into an array.

I begin by setting values and arrays and then iterating through the arrays and performing the calculation. Finally, I try to place the calculated output into an array filled with zeroes. However, I get the following error message:

"for i in range(b[0]): TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index."

Could someone please help me understand how to properly iterate through an array and perform calculations? Thank you for your time.

```
import numpy as np


S = np.linspace(0,37,100)
T = np.array([5.,25.,30.])


delta = 25. - T
f = 1575e6

tt = T.reshape(3,1)
beta = S*tt
b = np.zeros(np.shape(beta)).reshape(100,3)

#Calculate and put into a 3x100 or 100x3 array
for i in range(b[0]):
      for j in range(T[0]):
            b[i,j]= 1.00 + 2.282e-5*S[i]*[j] - 7.638e-4*S[i] - 7.76e-6*S[i]**2 + 1.105e-8*S[i]**3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a little unclear to me what exactly you are doing, but I was able to adapt your code and get it to work. First of all, `T[0]` is a float (.5) and won't work for your iterator. I am assuming you wanted to loop over the length of each variable to make `b` 100x3, in which case you should use `range(len(b[0]))`, or use a variable to define the length of `b[0]`, and use that variable to define your iterator as well.

Also, in the last line you put `j` in brackets, making it a list, which is unnecessary if you want it to multiply as a number. Did you want the iterator (0,1,2) to multiply `S[i]` or the specific value in `T`? I wrote the former below, but if you want the latter change `j` to `T[j]`

The following code runs without error for me

```
import numpy as np


S = np.linspace(0,37,100)
T = np.array([5.,25.,30.])


delta = 25. - T
f = 1575e6

tt = T.reshape(3,1)
beta = S*tt
length_of_b_0=100
b = np.zeros(np.shape(beta)).reshape(length_of_b_0,3)

#Calculate and put into a 3x100 or 100x3 array
for i in range(length_of_b_0):
      for j in range(len(T)):
            b[i,j]= 1.00 + 2.282e-5*S[i]*j - 7.638e-4*S[i] - 7.76e-6*S[i]**2 + 1.105e-8*S[i]**3
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, and sorry for not explaining that well. You're correct I was trying to iterate over the length of each variable. What you created below is what I was trying to do. Thank you for providing an explanation as well.

Comment: If this answers your question, could you select my response as the correct answer?

Comment: [This page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) explains how accepting an answer works